# How to echo out a specific value from a json response in PHP

Tags: php, json, rest

I was wondering what would be the best way to grab values from a JSON response like this?

```
{
"customer": {
  "link": {
    "url": "https://api.neteller.com/v1/customers/CUS_0d676b4b-0eb8-4d78-af25-e41ab431e325",
    "rel": "customer",
    "method": "GET"
}
},
"transaction": {
  "merchantRefId": "20140203113703",
  "amount": 2500,
  "currency": "EUR",
  "id": "176391453448397",
  "createDate": "2014-02-03T18:50:48Z",
  "updateDate": "2014-02-03T18:50:51Z",
  "status": "Accepted",
  "fees": [
    {
      "feeType": "Service_fee",
      "feeAmount": 71,
      "feeCurrency": "EUR"
    }
]
},
"links": [
  {
    "url": "https://api.neteller.com/v1/payments/176391453448397",
    "rel": "self",
    "method": "GET"
  }
]
}
```

I already have the response stored in a variable:

```
$content = json_decode($data['content']);
```

How do I echo these values in PHP? Let's say I want merchantRefId. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$content = json_decode($data['content'], true);
echo $content['transaction']['merchantRefId'];
```

Comment: Ahh yes, seems I had to set json_decode to true! Thanks! Would give +1, but don't have 15 rep yet :(

Comment: While this answer is valid, an answer with code only is less useful than an answer with an explanation. See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better*.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this here: [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f0779fcc8a6755c1e2928c5ed74b47ed9260b752)

`echo $content->transaction->merchantRefId;`

`json_decode()` generates an object of the standard class. You then use object notation to access the properties of that object.

Alternatively, you can use

`$content = json_decode($data['content'],true);`

And you'll get an associative array instead of an object. Then you'll be able to access it by element name like

`echo $content['transaction']['merchantRefId'];`

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode()` will build an associative array mapping your json, so if you do

```
echo "<PRE>"; print_r($content);
```

you will see how it was mapped to the array. Accessing the data would be something like

```
$merchantRefId = $content['transaction']['merchantRefId'];
```

Check how it was mapped using the `print_r()` function so you know how exactly it was mapped. At first, the way I exemplified seems the right one.

Comment: `json_decode()` does not build an associative array unless you tell it to, with the second parameter, boolean true. See my answer that covers both situations.